# Clearing Chrome extension localStorage from within popup.js

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I have everything in my extension working apart from one thing! I want to clear the local storage of this extension through popup.js. It's a simple extension that saves form data from a certain domain.

Currently, in my content script (save.js) I'm accessing local storage through localStorage[key] however it seems I'm unable to do this through popup.js and I get an 'undefined' which I assume it expected behaviour.

I have tried localStorage.clear(); from my popup.js but this has no effect. Presumably because it's looking to clear non existent localStorage from within the extension itself?

How can I access and clear the local storage that my save.js has been using from popup.js?

**popup.js**

```html
document.getElementById('clearAllData').addEventListener('click', clear);

function clear(){
 localStorage.clear();
 }
```

**Snippet of how I'm saving data in save.js**

```html
function saveTicket(ticket, contents) {
 localStorage[ticketID] = contents;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're not using the callback correctly. You need to pass the function asynchronously. For example:

```
function clear(){
   chrome.storage.local.clear(function(obj){
      console.log("cleared");
      });
 }
```

however it might be this as well. Chrome storage is already local.

```
function clear(){
   chrome.storage.sync.clear(function(obj){
      console.log("cleared");
      });
 }
```

Comment: This hasn't worked unfortunately. I'm not sure I understand what the obj should be? Shouldn't this just wipe the storage completely without needing to pass an object? PSA - I'm not sure what I'm talking about.

Comment: It's the response from the chrome extension after the function has resolved. You can leave it empty since you don't want the data.

Comment: Thanks, however the data still exists. It still doesn't appear to do anything

Comment: because you need to read the extensions storage section. localStorage != chrome.storage

Comment: Ohh, I see. I've updated my question to reflect this information.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) instead of localStorage. When you use localStorage in a content script, is it of the page, not of your extension. However, when you use chrome.storage in a content script, it is the storage of your extension.